# Where is mms.cfg (Flash Player configuration file) located in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, flash, flash-player

Where is mms.cfg, the Flash Player configuration file, located in Windows 8? I know in Windows 7 it is located at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg. But I can't seem to find it in Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the exact same location on Windows 8.

Comment: This is correct.  While the file may not exist, it can be manually created and used for the same benefit.